# php get data from one to many tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables A & B

```
Table A
       ID             NAME
       1              John
       2              Jack
       3              Mark

Table B
       ID             phone      UserID
       s1             4586         1
       s2             6996         1
       s3             9654         2
```

they are one to many relation (John has 2 phone on Table 2)

my sql query

```
$sql = 'SELECT * 
                FROM 
                A 
                Join
                B
                ON
                B.USER_ID = A.ID
                WHERE 
                A.ID=:ID';
```

my PHP

```
foreach($vars['GROUPS'] as $row) {


                <tr><th>Name</th><td><?=$row['Name']?></td></tr>
                <tr><th>phone</th><td><?=$row['phone']?></td></tr>


}
```

I want to show the phones number for this user John  name then show all his details from table 2 . as it now loop for me

Comment: Do you want to display both phone no front of John name?

Comment: I want show Name of John,then can show his phones numbers on another table under name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Use [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function in sql to concatenate all telephone numbers a user has into a single string and use pretty much the same loop in php as you use now.

   `select a.id, a.name, group_concat(b.phone) as phone
   from a inner join b on a.id=b.user_id
   group by a.id, a.name`
2. Leave your current sql query intact, but change the php loop displaying the table. In this case only print out a name with all the corresponding phone numbers after looping through all the records returned from the query. Just concatenate all phone numbers in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand your question right. From your query you get two rows for the user John, one is "1-John-s1-4586-1" and the other is "1-John-s2-6996-1", right? And you want just one row for that user containing both his phone numbers? Then you could use GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT A.*, GROUP_CONCAT(b.phone) FROM
A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.UserID
WHERE A.ID=:ID
GROUP BY A.id
```

See the MySQL documentation for more options of the GROUP_CONCAT function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

For example, you could use ordering or a custom separator.

In PHP you could use explode() if you want to iterate over the phone numbers.